# Selecting a specified range with Worksheets() causes runtime error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

In a workbook with three worksheets (ws1, ws2, and w3) this piece of code causes the runtime error "1004" when **ws2** is **not** active:

```vb
With Worksheets("ws2").Range(Range("O2"), Range("O2").End(xlDown)).Interior

    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.25

End With
```

I can't see why.

Comment: Try `With Worksheets("ws2").Range(Worksheets("ws2").Range("O2"), Worksheets("ws2").Range("O2").End(xlDown)).Interior`

Comment: As @Naresh has shown - you've qualified the overall range in `ws2` but your `Range("O2")` parts are looking at whatever sheet is active.  Also might be better to use  `Worksheets("ws2").Cells(Rows.Count,15).End(xlup)` if you want to capture the last cell containing data (Rows.Count should be qualified to, but generally all sheets have the same row count anyway).

Comment: Thanks @Naresh. It works now. And also thank you Darren Bartrup-Cook for the explainations.